# Использование Фрагментов

Tags: java, android

Добрый день.
Прочитал про фрагменты,не до конца понял логику их использования.
Использую паттерн MVC.
Имея две кнопки,переключения между двумя ListView.
Логику работы я могу сделать в фрагменте. Нажал на ListView и класс фрагмента через контроллер берет данные и возвращает, к примеру, SimpleCursorAdapterr и ListView или только должен использовать его для отображения виджетов,а логику хранить ActivityMain?

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что паттерн MVC реализуется системой Android "из коробки", где контроллером выступает активити (фрагмент), представлением - xml-разметка, а моделью - данные для отображения и специально реализовывать ничего не надо.
Фрагмент такой же контроллер, как и активити и свои виджеты должен "обслуживать" сам. Активии в этом случае выступает хостом - управляет самими фрагментами (их отображением, замещением или удалением) и их взаимодействием между собой, но не управляет их содержимым.
В иделае фрагмент ничего не должен знать о активити и выполнять свои функции в любой активити, а не специально для него написанной.

Другое дело, что сама по себе логика - это вообще не "область ответственности" контроллеров, ни активити ни фрагмента. Эти функции должны быть вынесены в другие классы, контроллер занимается только обработкой реакций на действия пользователя или изменением отображения виджетов на экране, делегируя выполнение этих действий дальше.